# Apache2 alias loading from document root instead of alias directory

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, static-content, documentroot, aliases

I have problem with apache2.
I'm new to it and I'm trying to solve some problems.
I have a server running debian with apache2.4 installed and 3 web-site running. A Shiny Server, a django website and a static website. The three sites are located differently
The Static webiste is a blogdown site located at /var/www/html/mysite  with an assigned alias to it mysite.com/blog/. The problem is that surf on that site i cannot load any css or I'm not able o access every subpage of this website. Instead of holding the /blog/link-to-some-page address apache2 is driving me to /link-to-some-page. Here my apache2 config file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /srv/dev-disk-by-label-disco1/django/wrkt-site
    

    <Directory /srv/dev-disk-by-label-disco1/django/wrkt-site>
    Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    
    Alias /static /srv/dev-disk-by-label-disco1/django/wrkt-site/static

    <Directory /srv/dev-disk-by-label-disco1/django/wrkt-site/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/dev-disk-by-label-disco1/django/wrkt-site>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    
            
 
WSGIDaemonProcess wrkt python-path=/srv/dev-disk-by-label-disco1/django/wrkt-site/ python-home=/srv/dev-disk-by-label-disco1/django/wrkt-site/venv
WSGIProcessGroup wrkt
WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/dev-disk-by-label-disco1/django/wrkt-site/wrkt/wsgi.py

Alias /blog "/var/www/html/mysite"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/mysite">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    

# Proxy rules
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On  
ProxyPass /stats-apps http://localhost:3333/    
ProxyPassReverse /stats-apps http://localhost:3333/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

And here there are the errors that errors.log is giving me:

```
[Mon Sep 27 15:01:23.486805 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6689] [remote XXX.XX.XX.XXX:60541] Not Found: /css/main.css 
[Mon Sep 27 15:01:23.504880 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6689] [remote XXX.XX.XX.XXX:58335] Not Found: /css/fonts.css
[Mon Sep 27 15:01:23.506045 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6689] [remote XXX.XX.XX.XXX:56566] Not Found: /images/logo.png
    [Mon Sep 27 15:01:23.507491 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6689] [remote XXX.XX.XX.XXX:50814] Not Found: /images/hugo-logo.png
```

I'm really in trouble to solve this.

Marco

Comment: The blogdown software should have an option to generate the links correctly with the `/blog` prefix you have chosen. Check its documentation carefully.

Comment: @MichaelHampton going in the `config.yaml` and modifying the `baseurl` parameter solved. The problem now is that if I try to access to a post of the blog, instead of `/blog/post-01` is giving me `/blog/blog/post-01` with all links for posts incorrects

Comment: I searched for some help in the guide [link](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/a-quick-example.html#configure-site) but I was not able to find something that helped me.